# Determine Hermite interpolation polynomial and evaluate the appropriate error.

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

Determine Hermite interpolation polynomial and evaluate the appropriate error

y:=f(x)

```
                                               xi || -1   0    1     2  
                                               yi || 4    6    2    10
```

I found Hermite interpolation polynomial:
$H_3= \frac{7}{3}x^3-\frac{7}{3}x^2-x+9$

but I don't know how to find error cause I need fourth derivative of f(x), but when I find f(x) using data from table i get function which doesn't have fourth derivative

Comment: Hermite interpolation usually includes some derivative values. Without them, one would call this Lagrange- or Newton interpolation.

Comment: I know but all I have are these data in table and I have to find Hermite interpolation so I found Hermite interpolation as Lagrange and I should find error too but don't know how cause I don't have fourth derivative of f(x)